How to delete tables and views inside BigQuery dataset based on name
So I need to specify the namem of the datasets as a variable and the script should delete all tables and views from this dataset that contain the suffix "_old".
So for example I list the dataset names like:
    datasets_to_be_deleted = [
      "test_project.test_dataset_1",
      "test_project.test_dataset_2",
      "test_project.test_dataset_3"
    ]

So this is the code that I think is close to what I want to achieve:
# Get the list of tables for each dataset
data "google_bigquery_tables" "tables" {
  for_each = toset(var.datasets_to_be_deleted)
 
  dataset_id = split(".", each.value)[1]
}
 
# Delete only tables with the _old suffix
resource "google_bigquery_table" "delete_bqdt_tables" {
  for_each = {
    for dataset, tables in data.google_bigquery_tables.tables : dataset => tables if can(regex("_old$", tables.table_id))
  }
 
  project   = split(".", each.key)[0]
  dataset_id = split(".", each.key)[1]
  table_id  = each.value.table_id
  deletion_protection = false
 
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
 
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "echo Deleting table ${self.table_id} from dataset ${self.dataset_id}"
  }
}

Problem is, each.value.table_id doesn't exist, I don't know how can I print out this object during terraform plan to see what the attributes are.
So the same logic could be used to delete the views by specifying view resource, but I can't find such resource in the documentation.
Please guide me how to get this to work.
